# Not able to ssh in to GCP compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to gcp, Created custom VPC and launched new compute engine instance in same vpc but unable to ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you select the firewall rules while creating VPC. if not you can create firewall rule.

The following links help you to troubleshoot and creating firewall rules in GCP.

[1]. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh.

[2]. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls.